# Flutter - Fetch signature of a user from Web3Auth

Tags: flutter, web3auth

I need to fetch the signed message of a user that has been authenticated using Web3Auth.

There is a function in React that helps fetching the same, as below:
const web3 = new Web3(this.provider);

```
  const fromAddress = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0];

  const originalMessage = "YOUR MESSAGE";

  const signedMessage = await web3.eth.personal.sign(
    originalMessage,
    fromAddress,
    "YOUR PASSWORD"
  );

  return signedMessage;
```

How do I get the same result in Flutter?
I am using [web3auth_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/web3auth_flutter) package for the authentication